# Understanding notation for input space

Tags: dataset, notation, function

I'm taking the free [Caltech machine learning course](https://work.caltech.edu/lectures.html).  I'm having trouble understanding the notation [on one of the problems](https://work.caltech.edu/homework/hw1.pdf):

> In this problem, you will create your own target function f and data set D to see
> how the Perceptron Learning Algorithm works. Take d = 2 so you can visualize the
> problem, and assume X = [−1, 1] × [−1, 1] with uniform probability of picking each
> x ∈ X .

What does it mean that `X = [−1, 1] × [−1, 1]` ? what does the x or times symbol mean?  Is this a continuous range or discrete set of elements?  Basically what values can be in X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X consists of all elements $$x = (x_1, x_2) $$ such that $$x_1 , x_2 \in [-1,1]$$
That is
$$ -1 \le x_i \le 1$$ for $i = 1,2$

You should consider taking a course in calculus.

The 'x' is the notation for a product space.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the notation for a 'product space', what that is, and an example of the operation and its result?

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product . Cartesian Product might have been a better description.

Comment: oh cartesian product, got it